# How can I webscrape a results page when it has the same URL as the search page?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm working on webscraping a website that is the results page. I've been trying to use the 'rvest' package method (outlined nicely in this [blog post](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-in-r-rvest/)), and was confused why it wasn't returning results. I realized it's because the URL I was using is the same URL from the home search page and the results page, so when R opens up the URL, it does not see the search results which I want to scrape data from.

Is there any way around this?

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: does it have to be `rvest`?  the blog post mentions `BeautifulSoup` too.

Comment: Most modern webpages use javascript to update their content. Tools like `rvest` cannot execute javascript for you like a web browser would. You'd need to use tools like RSelenium or try to open your browser devtools to see if you can figure out where the data is actually coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider an approach based on RSelenium :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-in-r-rvest/"
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)
remDr$screenshot(TRUE)
```

You can also consider an approach based on RDCOMClient :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
url <- "https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-in-r-rvest/"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(5)
doc <- IEApp$Document()
```